# Django options field with categories

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following code in my models.py(removed irrelevant fields):

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    choice_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    planguages = models.ManyToManyField(Choices)
```

and my utils.py(originaly from django-profiles, that's parsing forms):

```
def get_profile_form():
    profile_mod = get_profile_model()
    class _ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        planguages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Choices.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

        class Meta:
            model = profile_mod
            exclude = ('user',) # User will be filled in by the view.
    return _ProfileForm
```

Now, what I'd like to do is to have a table Choices, that will have the `name` and `choice_type` columns, which I already have. The problem is that I don't really know how can I tie an option to a category, and make a user, when they're creating their profile, pick an programming language or a framework, based on choice in `choice_type`.

I assume it'd involve some JS, but that's not as much of a problem as django code.

Comment: can you expand on this a little? you want to restrict a user to picking from certain categories based on plang?

Comment: @Thomas nope, it's the other way round. I want a to have user being able to pick programming languages and frameworks they have experience with. `choice_type` is going to have these options: programming language, markup/scripting language, framework.

So, I want to restrict certain choices(ie. `name`) to a certain categories (ie. `choice_type`).

Comment: where are you storing data on what they have experience with?

Comment: @Thomas in database. in myapp_choices table.

Comment: @Thomas so, `name` is a column for languages/frameworks they have experience with, and `choice_type` is a column for the category.

Comment: your not really being clear on what you want. do you wish to dynamically filter the options available to the user based on affinity to plang, or simply display a list grouped by choice_type?

Comment: @Thomas, I prefer latter. And sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're going to want to make these actual models, so you'd have something like this:

```
class ProgrammingCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProgrammingLanguage(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProgrammingCategory, related_name='languages')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    planguages = models.ManyToManyField(ProgrammingLanguage)
```

Not only is this better from a maintainability standpoint (programming languages do change: new ones come around, old ones die out), but it also gives you much greater flexibility in querying.

Then, you simply add a field to your `ModelForm` for the categories:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProgrammingCategory.objects.all(), required=False)
```

And, in your form, you'll end up with a select with a complete list of categories and another with a complete list of languages. Then, all you need is some AJAX to do the filtering for you:

**views.py**

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest

def ajax_get_languages_for_category(request):
    cat_id = request.GET.get('cat_id')
    if cat_id is not None:
        category = get_object_or_404(ProgrammingCategory, id=cat_id)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', category.languages.all())
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $category = $('#id_category');
    function updateLanguageChoices() {
        var selected = $category.val();
        if (selected) {
            $.getJSON('/path/to/ajax/view/', { cat_id: selected }, function (data, jqXHR) {
                var output = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, item){
                    output.append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.name+'</option>');
                });
                $('#id_planguage').html(output.join(''));
            });
        }
    }
    updateLanguageChoices();
    $category.change(updateLanguageChoices);
});
```

Comment: I need 15 rep points to vote up your answer, but if I had, I'd give it 200 votes, if I could. Thanks a lot!