# Django: how can I a create categories field/dropdown menu?

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, model, categories

This is a very simple question, how can I create dropdown field in Django with only specific categories(something similar to the countries dropdown, but not with countries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [choice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices) attribute of a Field if it is for fixed values. Or with a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field if the Categories should be created dynamicly.

For the ForeignKey field you would do the following:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    # ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the second option?

Comment: @Antoni4040: Updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Django's most powerful feature is to offer you direct forms.
It's a broad question but you want to define a model that can be paired with a form that you can put in a template.
Take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/ and here:
[Django options field with categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966657/django-options-field-with-categories) and here [Creating a dynamic choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field)

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear. I mean a categories field for the database. The dropdown menu will be in the admin page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what you want to achieve. Do you want a limited number of categories or a field in the database where you can define as many categories as you like? Are you looking something like this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

Comment: You could call it a textfield but with a limited amount of possible values, and I want to be able to add more options in the future. I'm sorry, I don't know how else to describe it...

Comment: You can use ChoiceField with choices. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field